# picasso doesn't display picture in my ImageView what should I do?

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-glide

I can load image URL but picasso or glide can't display them in imageView(try both of them). any solution ?
I think there is some thing wrong with my classes or my adapter because when I call them some of them returns null, I don't know whats wrong with it but I can get ImageUrl , I check the spelling and that was ok.

```
String imageUri = photo.getPhotoURL().getRegular();
    Log.d("photo_log"," : "+imageUri);
    Picasso.get().load(imageUri).into(holder.photo);
```

and this is my logcat

```
 D/photo_log:  : https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633113089631-6456cccaadad?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwyNzc5MDJ8MXwxfGFsbHwxfHx8fHx8Mnx8MTYzODEyNDQ3MQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080
```

this is my Photo class

```
package com.example.wallpaperapp.Model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Photo {

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
@SerializedName("description")
private String description;
@SerializedName("urls")
private PhotoURL photoURL=new PhotoURL();
@SerializedName("users")
private User user=new User();

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public PhotoURL getPhotoURL() {
    return photoURL;
}

public void setPhotoURL(PhotoURL photoURL) {
    this.photoURL = photoURL;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
}
```

this is my User class

```
package com.example.wallpaperapp.Model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class User {

@SerializedName("first_name")
private String firstName;
@SerializedName("last_name")
private String lastName;
@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
@SerializedName("profile_image")
private ProfileImage profileImage=new ProfileImage();

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public ProfileImage getProfileImage() {
    return profileImage;
}

public void setProfileImage(ProfileImage profileImage) {
    this.profileImage = profileImage;
}
}
```

and this is my adapter

```
public class photoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<photoAdapter.ViewHolder> {


private Context context;
private List<Photo> photos;


public photoAdapter(Context context, List<Photo> photos) {
    this.context = context;
    this.photos = photos;
}




 @NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.photo_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Photo photo = photos.get(position);
    holder.userName.setText(photo.getId());
    String imageUri = photo.getPhotoURL().getRegular();
    Picasso.get().load(imageUri).into(holder.photo);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return photos.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CircleImageView userAvatar;
    TextView userName;
    ImageView photo;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        userAvatar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_user_avatar);
        userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_user_name);
        photo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo_item_recycler);



       }
    }
}
```

I also put the URL directly into `.load()` but still doesn't show the image

Comment: Can you post the code where you're setting the image URL?

Comment: yes I added please check it again

Comment: Picasso will not help when image url is with https try using glide instead

Comment: I used glide too doesn't change the result

Comment: have you added an internet permission in Manifest? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: yes I added permissions

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this in order to get more information about the error

```java
Picasso.with(context)
      .load(imageUri)
      .into(holder.photo, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                  // add log
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                  // add log and printstack trace
                }
            })
```

You could also set an "error image" from the drawable to see if the problem comes from your adapter or not :

```java
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUri)
    .error(R.drawable.my_error_image)
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: thanks ,i found the error